# Plotting groupby with Pandas vs. Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm new to Pandas, sorry if this question is trivial or doesn't make much sense.

Suppose I have the following dataframe (taken from the [doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
        'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
        'C' : np.random.randn(8),
        'D' : np.random.randn(8)}
)
```

Value:

```
     A      B         C         D
0  foo    one -1.591757  0.016910
1  bar    one  0.540010  1.022113
2  foo    two -1.134974 -1.600034
3  bar  three  0.082130 -0.221179
4  foo    two  0.252851  1.963539
5  bar    two -3.012450  0.815712
6  foo    one -0.243863  0.615665
7  foo  three -2.558635 -2.405591
```

I calculate the mean on columns C and D for any value of B:

```
result = df.groupby("B").mean()
```

Value:

```
              C         D
B                        
one   -0.431870  0.551563
three -1.238253 -1.313385
two   -1.298191  0.393072
```

I can plot the resulting table with the `plot` method of `DataFrame`:

```
result.plot()
```

[image: dataframe plot method]

Now, if I want to manipulate further the plot, and use directly `plt.plot` instead, the legends are missing and the abscissa labels replaced by a numeric index:

```
plt.plot(result)
```

[image: plt plot method]

How could I obtain the same plot with `plt.plot`?

Comment: which version of python, pandas and matplotlib are you using? For mine: `3.4.3, 0.17.1, 1.5.0` with `plt.plot(result)` I've got an error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'two'`

Comment: Respectively: `2.7.10, 0.16.2, 1.4.3` (Anaconda distribution). The offending line definitely doesn't raise any exception for me. Anyway, it doesn't give me the desired plot either :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a reference to the plot and go from there with standard matplotlib commands.

```
p = plt.subplot(111)
p.plot(result)
p.legend(['C', 'D'])
plt.xticks(list(range(len(result))), result.index)
plt.xlabel(result.index.name)
```

[image]

Version with a reference to the plot. Useful when you have multiple plots:

```
p = plt.subplot(111)
p.plot(result)
p.legend(['C', 'D'])
p.set_xticks(list(range(len(result))))
p.set_xticklabels(result.index)
p.set_xlabel(result.index.name)
```

Comment: Yes, I think this is equivalent (without `subplot`) to: `plt.plot(result); plt.legend(['C', 'D']); plt.show()`. But do you know how to restore the abscissa labels?

Comment: Added a version with labels.

Comment: @MikeMüller but in pandas you'll have 2 level label on X axis, in your case it's only one.

Comment: OK. Now with second level label.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly the result I was looking for. The `subplot` thing still looks strange to my newbie eyes, but I guess it's the pandaic way to go!

Comment: @Aristide  Well, subplots are only needed if you're doing multiple graphs on one canvas or figure. So you don't need it in this case, but people just stick with it out of habit.